# Macbookpro keeps crashing with kernel panic

Tags: kernel, panic

From a few weeks ago my Mac is crash randomly with kernel panic. My machine is macbookpro 15 min2012 and is running Mojave. The kernel panic report is as follow. Each time it crashed it products the similar report

```
Anonymous UUID:       A3CB7EA6-06A0-4396-AC91-B1CFE20BB7B1

Thu Aug 27 19:50:51 2020

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 3 caller 0xffffff802e5f84bb): "Bad tailq elm 0xffffff8050ee69b0 next->prev != elm"@/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-4903.271.2/bsd/vfs/vfs_subr.c:673
mp = 0xffffff804ee8ecc0, phys = 0x1f04a1cc0, prev (0xb: 0xffe70000-0xffea0000)
vp = 0xffffff8050ee69b0, phys = 0x41d6ca9b0, prev (0xb: 0xffe70000-0xffea0000)
0xffffff804ee8d000: IUMAAG1hcCBEAy1ob3NIA3RzAABMA4DzglNYB4D///9cBwAAAgBgBwAAAgBkByAAAABoByAAAABsBwAAAgBwBwAAAgB0B/8PAAB4BwACAAB8ByAAAACABwEAAACEBwAAACHIB//////kBz8AAAD4B5v///8oCJv///8sCAA+oVAwCID///80CHAh2FNACID///9ECCeQMwtICA0AAABMCAIAAABQCP////98CGDO6E6ACID///+ECOD26E6ICID///+MCAUAAACQCP////+kCKCw7K+oCH////+sCGCCCk+wCID///+0CNBVSk+4CID///+8CNA1+lTACID////ECCBvSk/ICID////MCNDY6E7YCID////cCODY6E7oCID////sCASQkBTwCAAAXYD0CAAQAAAECQAAEAAICWQzvAgQCVQznAgYCbKmNQEgCRAAIAAoCf////8wCf///380Cf7///84Cf///388CQgAAAFACRkAAABECQSQkBRMCWFwZnNUCS9wcmlkCXZhdGVoCS92YXJsCS92bQBwCS9kZXZkDS9kaXNoDWsxczRsDQAA
0xffffff804ee8e000: 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
0xffffff804ee8f000: 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
Backtrace (CPU 3), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff9248633af0 : 0xffffff802e3ae6ed 
0xffffff9248633b40 : 0xffffff802e4ea185 
0xffffff9248633b80 : 0xffffff802e4db8ba 
0xffffff9248633bf0 : 0xffffff802e35bb40 
0xffffff9248633c10 : 0xffffff802e3ae107 
0xffffff9248633d30 : 0xffffff802e3adf53 
0xffffff9248633da0 : 0xffffff802e5f84bb 
0xffffff9248633e50 : 0xffffff7fafe1f9c7 
0xffffff9248633ea0 : 0xffffff802e609602 
0xffffff9248633ec0 : 0xffffff802e5f8239 
0xffffff9248633f30 : 0xffffff802e609537 
0xffffff9248633f40 : 0xffffff802e9ba5ed 
0xffffff9248633fa0 : 0xffffff802e35c306 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.filesystems.apfs(945.275.7)[ACFDCC84-EBFD-376E-8361-B16CC6CAF740]@0xffffff7fafdcc000->0xffffff7fafecdfff
            dependency: com.apple.kec.corecrypto(1.0)[16D0DE4A-4774-32C4-B05D-D35601D9FC39]@0xffffff7faf365000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage(1.0)[10658FF3-EB34-3240-9E63-3FB47B9700FF]@0xffffff7fafc86000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily(2.1)[71BB22B0-3075-35A1-B04E-FBAC574DA80D]@0xffffff7faeec9000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: launchd

Mac OS version:
18G103

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 18.7.0: Tue Aug 20 16:57:14 PDT 2019; root:xnu-4903.271.2~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: C41337A1-0EC3-3896-A954-A1F85E849D53
Kernel slide:     0x000000002e000000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff802e200000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff802e100000
System model name: MacBookPro9,1 (Mac-4B7AC7E43945597E)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 33785858437822
last loaded kext at 14892031382682: com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3 (addr 0xffffff7fb208a000, size 32768)
last unloaded kext at 393401803076: com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   5.6.9 (addr 0xffffff7fb207b000, size 49152)
loaded kexts:
com.intel.kext.intelhaxm    6.2.1
com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs   1.10
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch   96
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.fileutil  20.036.15
com.apple.AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics  3.50.12
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    6.0.14d3
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.5
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.25.11
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    131
com.apple.GeForce   12.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   12.1.0
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AGDCBacklightControl   3.50.12
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   282.54
com.apple.driver.eficheck   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   282.54
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.50.12
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 12.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    212
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.5.9
com.apple.filesystems.ntfs  3.13
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  255
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 255
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  354
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  408.250.3
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  945.275.7
com.apple.driver.AppleVirtIO    2.1.3
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  407.200.4
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.AppleSystemPolicy 1.0
com.apple.private.KextAudit 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.7.6
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.6.0
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.3.3
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   1400.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  329.260.5
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 220.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   201
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   220.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   6.0.14d3
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  2450.1
com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport    2440.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAVBFamily 760.6
com.apple.plugin.IOgPTPPlugin   740.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSkywalkFamily 1
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal    12.0.0
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman  12.0.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 282.54
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    528
com.apple.AppleGPUWrangler  3.50.12
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   530.51
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 282.54
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 282.54
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.50.12
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    404.14
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   255.6.1
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.50.12
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.3.0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.18d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    530.66
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   208
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 6.0.14d3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   6.0.14d3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  6.0.14d3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   6.0.14d3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 263
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBAudio  315.6
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   206.5
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  408.250.3
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.8
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   267.50.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  301.270.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    5.6.9
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    5.6.9
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.7.9
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.8.6
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.7.3
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    288
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 493.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    456.260.3
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  145.200.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   408.250.3
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   408.250.3
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.kext.CoreTrust    1
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    740.2
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  47
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0

EOF
Model: MacBookPro9,1, BootROM 232.0.0.0.0, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.6 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.1f173
Graphics: kHW_IntelHD4000Item, Intel HD Graphics 4000, spdisplays_builtin
Graphics: kHW_NVidiaGeForceGT650MItem, NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, spdisplays_pcie_device, 1 GB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x0000, -
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x0000, -
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xF5), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.190.33 AirPortDriverBrcm4360-1325.2)
Bluetooth: Version 6.0.14d3, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: APPLE HDD HTS541075A9E682, 750.16 GB
Serial ATA Device: OPTIARC DVD RW AD-5970H
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Microsoft® LifeCam Studio(TM)
USB Device: Keyboard Hub
USB Device: Griffin PowerMate
USB Device: Apple Keyboard
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 25.1
```

it looks like GPU driver problem but not sure how and where to start. Can anyone have an idea of how to interpret the report?

Many thx